# Loop Through 1 to n until end of Row

Tags: vba, excel

Basically, I have a namelist that I want to divide them into n number of groups, say 4, for example.

I have the names in Column A, and the Group Number in Column D, and my code that seemed to work are as follow:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim S As Long, E As Long, I As Long, N As Long, a As Long, b As Long
With ActiveSheet
    N = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(N, 4)).ClearContents
    S = 1 'smallest number
    E = 4 'largest numbr
    I = N / 4 'times of repeat
    N = 1
    For a = 1 To I Step 1
        For b = S To E Step 1
            .Cells(N + 1, 4).Value = b
            N = N + 1
        Next b
    Next a
End With
End Sub
```

The issue for this design is that if the number of rows is not fully divided by 4, a blank row will be created with the remaining numbers inputted. This is not what I want, sadly, as I need to concat the data and mail merge them onto Word. The current solution will create blank entry for my produced documents instead.

I wonder if anyone can help me out as I'm not an expert on VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found a stupid solution by simply deleting the entire row by detecting where Column A's cell is empty

```
On Error Resume Next
Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```